# Images not showing up when i deploy my app to gh-pages

Tags: html, reactjs, github-pages

I've seen so many solutions but most involve relative links.

mine is an Image Url and I'm finding it difficult to load.

```
export const Card = (props) => (
    <div className = 'card-container'>
        <img src={`https:\\robohash.org/${props.monster.id}?set=set2&size=180x180`} alt="monster"/>
        <h2 > {props.monster.name}</h2>
        <p>
            {props.monster.email}
        </p>
    </div>

);
```

This is the error I get in my console

```
6:1 GET https://tooluloope.github.io/www.robohash.org/6?set=set2&size=180x180 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that the image source URL in the question's code is incorrectly formatted with backslashes (`\\`) instead of forward slashes (`//`). That breaks the protocol portion of the URL (`https://`), so the app concludes it's a relative link and tries to add it onto `https://tooluloope.github.io/`, creating `https://tooluloope.github.io/www.robohash.org/`.

Change:

```
https:\\robohash.org/
```

to:

```
https://robohash.org/
```

- [Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gifted-lamarr-vkosq)
- [What is a URL? docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)